# Dynamic column create from child table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two table one for master and another child. Which is depicting below

**Master table:**
[image]

and scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SET_HRShiftProfile](
    [id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [LocationID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [ShiftTypeID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [ProfileName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EmpTypeCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_HR_ShiftProfile] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**Child Table:**
[image]
And script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SET_HRShiftProfileDetail](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LocationID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [ShiftprofileID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [ShiftProfTypeCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Start] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [End] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [ToleranceBefore] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [ToleranceAfter] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SET_HRShiftProfileDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I need to final query result look like this, means all child table row will be column for master table
[image]

Any idea give me appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with pivoted as
(
    select LocationID, ShiftprofileID, [IN], [OUT], [Break]
    from (
        select distinct LocationID, ShiftprofileID, [ShiftProfTypeCode]
        from [dbo].[SET_HRShiftProfileDetail]
    ) as t
    pivot (
        count([ShiftProfTypeCode]) for [ShiftProfTypeCode] in ([IN], [OUT], [Break])
    ) as p
)
select p.*
, x.[IN], x.[OUT], x.[Break]
from [dbo].[SET_HRShiftProfile] as p
left join pivoted x on x.ShiftprofileID = p.id
    and x.locationid = p.locationid
```

Results:

```
id      LocationID  ShiftTypeID ProfileName EmpTypeCode IsActive    IN  OUT Break
1003    1           1001        Day-Summar  REG         1           1   1   1
1006    1           1005        Say-Winter  REG         1           1   1   0
```

Since you said nothing about what data you like to get into cells, I have placed there the count of rows with such value (as column name) from the child table.

Hope it will help you to solve your problem

---

**LATER EDIT**

Solution without using PIVOT:

```
with pivoted as
(
    select LocationID
    , ShiftprofileID
    , sum(case when [ShiftProfTypeCode] = 'OUT' then 1 else 0 end) [OUT]
    , sum(case when [ShiftProfTypeCode] = 'IN' then 1 else 0 end) [IN]
    , sum(case when [ShiftProfTypeCode] = 'Break' then 1 else 0 end) [Break]
    from [dbo].[SET_HRShiftProfileDetail]
    group by LocationID, ShiftprofileID
)
select p.*
, x.[IN], x.[OUT], x.[Break]
from [dbo].[SET_HRShiftProfile] as p
left join pivoted x on x.ShiftprofileID = p.id
    and x.locationid = p.locationid
```

Results:

```
id      LocationID  ShiftTypeID ProfileName EmpTypeCode IsActive    IN  OUT Break
1003    1           1001        Day-Summar  REG         1           1   1   1
1006    1           1005        Say-Winter  REG         1           1   1   0
```

Comment: Hi, is this possible without pivot?